# Не получается использовать ассинхронность в django

Tags: python, django, асинхронность, asyncio

Я пытаюсь вызвать синхронную функцию в контексте ассинхронности в представлении Django следующим образом:

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import *
from django.http import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import *
from django.db import connection
from .models import *
import random
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync, sync_to_async

def execcute(query):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall() #get all strings of answer
        return rows 

async def main(request):

    funk = sync_to_async(execcute("SELECT * FROM BLOG"), thread_sensitive=True)

    list_of_states = await asyncio.run(funk)

    return render(request , "main.html")
```

На что получаю ошибку:

SynchronousOnlyOperation at /

You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

Как мне исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Это синтаксис у вас так подсвечивается, а не ошибка возникает. Запустите, получите ошибку, и уже показывайте.

Comment: Функция run() в asyncio предназначена для старта асинхронного кода из синхронного. И причем не где попало, а один раз в программе, так как порождает главный цикл событий asyncio. Сама по себе она синхронна и с await быть ни как не может https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine